# Submiting a form using ajax inside colorbox.js

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im using a form inside colorbox.js popup window. I want to submit the data using ajax but it doesn't work.

here is the link i click to show the popup colorbox.js window:

```
<a href="demande-emploi.php" class="ajax cboxElement" title="Demande d'emploi">Demanded'emploi</a>
```

here is the content of (demande-emploi.php) file:

```html
<div style="height:450px; width:580px; padding:30px 10px; margin: 0 auto;"> 
     
    <div id="message"></div>

 <form action="" method="POST">
   <div class="clearfix">          
   <div class="input">
    <label class="labels"> Poste à offrir:</label>
    <input type="text" id="poste_to_offre">
   </div>
  </div>     
  <div class="clearfix">          
          <div class="input">
              <label class="labels"> A propos:</label>
                  <textarea rows="9" id="apropos" class="textareas"></textarea>
          </div>
  </div>
   
  <div class="input">
   <label class="labels">Ville:</label>
   <input type="text" name="ville">
  </div>     
  <div class="clearfix">          
   <div class="input">
    <label class="labels">Tél/GSM:</label>
    <input type="text" id="tel">
   </div>
  </div> 
    
  <div class="clearfix">          
   <div class="input">
    <label class="labels"> Adresse:</label>
    <textarea rows="3" id="address" class="textareas"></textarea>
   </div>
  </div>    
  <br>
  <button type="submit" class="wpb_btn-small" id="send">Envoyer</button>
 </form> 
</div>
```

Here, I just want to test if the callback of the ID=send will respond or not but it doesn't work.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#send").on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();    
            $("#message").html("Blah Blah Blah......");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What console says? I thin you get error because `$(#send)` must be `$('#send')`. And i see no ajax call here.

Comment: what is that `e.preventDefault();` that doesn't make sense, and missing `'` single quotes on `$(#send)`. and plus, that should submit

Comment: @Ghost It's just a misplaced code.

Comment: @Justinas : $("#send") <-- I just typed it here wrong